# What's the difference with using "And" and "Between" in the where clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I was using these statements

```
DECLARE @FirstDayofPrevMonth datetime
SET @FirstDayofPrevMonth = DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE())-1,0)
DECLARE @LastDayofPrevMonth datetime
SET @LastDayofPrevMonth = DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE()),0))
```

and then using them in a where clause like so:

```
WHERE FNDate    >= @FirstDayofPrevMonth AND FNDate <= @LastDayofPrevMonth
```

What would be the reason to use "Between"?

Comment: For dates/datetimes, between can be confusing.  Check this out:  https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common.

Comment: Do you have a timestamp to worry about in `FNDate`? Then between will not work as you expect it to, you need `FNDate < @LastDayofPrevMonth + 1`

Comment: In addition to reading my post about `BETWEEN`, please [read this very carefully](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations.aspx) (stop using lazy shorthand) and also be mindful [that there is a bug in how cardinality is determined for this `DATEDIFF` calculation](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/09/t-sql-queries/datediff-bug).

Comment: @DanielE. yes there is a timestamp in this case

Comment: @AaronBertrand are you saying in your post, that this structure I have used is not how you would capture the data for prior month?

Comment: For prior month I would use [these two calculations](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/39103).

Answer (score 4):

`BETWEEN` is effectively the same thing as `>=` and `<=`.

Note that though it is less typing it can lead to possible wrong results.

Many times you want to get results within a single date. You would write:

```
WHERE DateTimeField BETWEEN '20140918' AND '20140919'
```

In this case, lets say that there are the following entries in the table:

```
1 '20140918 23:59:59'
2 '20140919 00:00:00'
3 '20140919 00:00:01'
```

The above `where` statement would get entries 1 and 2. So though in most of the times you would get the correct results, it is **much more safer** to use the following:

```
WHERE DateTimeField >='20140918' AND DateTimeField < '20140919'
```

Comment: However, if you wanted a specific date, wouldn't you just use **WHERE date = <insertDatehere>**? rather than a between date?

Comment: @jbutler483 If the field in the table is of `DATETIME` type, then you would either `CONVERT` or `CAST` it to a `DATE` type, which is not a good idea as it would impact performance. Note that `20140918` is never equal to '20140918 23:59:59'.

Comment: tbh i'm not entirely sure if the OP is using dates and times, or just times? but other than that, I would have to agree (however, in your answer I you are doing something similar? saying it's >=20140918?

Comment: @jbutler483 In my example and lets say that we need 19th of September, `DateTimeField = '20140919'` will get only entry number 2 as `'20140919 00:00:00'` is equal to `'20140919'`. `DateTimeField >='20140919' AND DateTimeField < '20140920'` will get both entries 2 and 3.

Comment: You almost got it.  At the very end, it should be < '20140920' in order to capture the 3rd record.

Comment: @DanBracuk In my answer i am trying to get 18th of September 2014, so i want only entry 1.

Comment: This is the only answer that addresses the timestamp, while both are functionally equivalent, they are both WRONG if there is a timestamp as OP has indicated. You need to use `FNDate < @LastDayofPrevMonth + 1` to capture all of the last day of the period.

Answer (score 2):

In the case that you are showing there is absolutely no reason to use `BETWEEN`: the two expressions are functionally equivalent.

A good case for `BETWEEN` is when the value on the left is a result of evaluating an expression, or a reference to a parameter, for example

```
WHERE @AsOfDate BETWEEN t.ActiveFrom AND t.ActiveTo
```

or

```
WHERE DATEADD(day, t.DaysToDeliver, t.OrderDate) BETWEEN @BlackoutBegin AND @BlackoutEnd
```

Here, an equivalent pair of `>=` and `<=` would require repeating part of the `WHERE` clause, which is not as readable as `BETWEEN` operator.

Comment: I agree though there is always an argument that explicit is better than implicit.... On the one hand foo >= bar and foo <= woo is more text to read than foo BETWEEN bar AND woo but on the other hand you have to remember that BETWEEN is INCLUSIVE - at least the conditional makes that very explicit.

Answer (score 2):

There's little to no difference, only that one could be argued as being easier to read.

For example, People could argue that:

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name BETWEEN value1 AND value2;
```

is easier to read than:

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name >=value1 AND column_name <=value2;
```

Otherwise, there isn't exactly much difference. Except more typing, for course (thanks Jake) ;)

Some people would still disagree though that they don't like the 'BETWEEN' clause, as it can sometimes be tricky with dates/etc. However, as with all code, it was designed for a reason. And, if used properly, can be very helpful!

Some would argue day and night that they'd use the AND clause - and that could be simply down to them knowing/using it more often, and have got used to it's little 'tweaks and twerks' - and so they haven't used the BETWEEN statement as much.

However, if they'd used the BETWEEN statement first (before they knew what the AND statement was), then they'd argue differently.

but again, as with all code, use it enough and you'll learn to use it - and possibly even think 'how did i NOT use this before'.

**EDIT**

as obviously some people are talking about the 'does the include/exclude', I thought I might add this (copied from my comment below):

Less typing might not always be the answer for a novice, but someone who knows what they're doing, it can be quite helpful! (i'm not a pro by any means) - but BETWEEN to me would imply exclusive. But yes, i understand where people are coming from, esp examples such as pick a number between 1 and 10. The whole word in the english language has some ambiguity!!!

If you want to read more, there is this [blog](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries) post talking about *"Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries"*.

[This](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/between.php) gives a little explaination as to *"Learn how to use the SQL BETWEEN condition with syntax and examples"*

Personally, I would prefer to reserve use the **Between** statement more for say, employee ID's, where the values are ints/etc, rather than dates (this is purely preference, as both would be 'fine' to use).

Comment: You need `>=` and `<=`.

Comment: Also option one is less typing. Always a plus.

Comment: @Jake Less typing is not always correct. Check my answer.

Comment: @Jake less typing is NOT always a plus and is actually sometimes much worse. You type the code once; the difference is milliseconds at best. Now think about the people who have to maintain the code or understand it - especially if you've used lazy shorthand for brevity. [Have a read of #6 here (and the links)](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-wrong-optimizations) and also [why you usually don't want BETWEEN even if it is "less typing"](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common).

Comment: I find BETWEEN confusing because it seems to imply non-inclusive endpoints.  Using AND allows you to be explicit about whether the specified endpoints are inclusive (>= and <=) or exclusive (> and <) or some mixture (>= and <)

Comment: Less typing might not always be the answer for a novice, but someone who knows what they're doing, it can be quite helpful! (i'm not a pro by any means) - but BETWEEN to me would imply exclusive. But yes, i understand where people are coming from, esp examples such as **pick a number between 1 and 10.** The whole word in the english language has some ambiguity!!!

Comment: @jbutler483 I know what I'm doing and I still prefer to be explicit and as self-documenting as possible. Why? Not because I want to type more or like to spend more time at the computer, but because I know that later I will curse myself for obfuscating things so much to save a few characters, or co-workers will ask me what the heck this shorthand means, or people here will "learn" that shorthand is a good habit. And yes, I do agree with the additional point that BETWEEN is ambiguous in English, too.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference in the key word **between** and **<= or >=** . They will give same result. 
But between is but for readable purpose and don't repeat the column name as well.

```
select * from table_name where column_name between '2014-01-01' and '2014-01-31';

select * from table_name where column_name>='2014-01-01' and date<='2014-01-31';
```

You can see it in above queries they will give same result but **between** is in readable format.

Answer (score 0):

As I recall, there's no difference. But see for yourself if:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `date` BETWEEN 12917700 AND 12917300
and:


SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `date` >= 12917700 AND `date` <= 12917300
```

**produce the same results.**

Comment: Why are you using MySQL syntax? Your ` around entities are incorrect for SQL Server, and I'm pretty sure those integers you're using won't work the way you expect (or they're at best completely obfuscated).