# relating rows based on begin_date and end_date

Tags: mysql, sql

Lets say we have a poorly designed DB.

A managers table and employees table, which are unrelated.

There is only ever one manager employed. Each has a begin date and an end date, so

```
Emp_begin    Emp_end
```

`Man_begin    Man_end`.

How could i write a query that would show all employees hired `between '1930-01-01' AND '1960-01-01'`, and the manager that was in place at the time of their hiring (`Emp_begin`)

Would appreciate any and all help

Comment: Searching for *Between clause SQL* might help. Here's an on going SO question you could possibly make use of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25912308/whats-the-difference-with-using-and-and-between-in-the-where-clause/25912445?noredirect=1#comment40584561_25912445

Comment: SELECT EmployeeName FROM employees E
LEFT JOIN managers M ON E.ManegerId = M.ManagerId
WHERE Emp_begin >= '1930-01-01' AND Emp_end <= '1960-01-01' AND Man_begin >= '1930-01-01' AND Man_end <= '1960-01-01'

Comment: why are these not related?

Comment: You can not do that without a reference of an manager hiring that employee... you need a managerId on the employee table !!
Else you can not get true results !

Comment: @SanRyu, incorrect.. you have everything you need here.

Comment: Ive been given an assignment, and have to create queries on the database provided, i think they may have overlooked the fact that the 2 tables are not realted. they arent manager and employee, theyre different names but for the sake of simplicity i changed the names, still the question is the same, the tables are not related and i have to match up one field with another based off date alone

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT EmployeeName FROM employees E 
LEFT JOIN managers M ON E.ManegerId = M.ManagerId 
WHERE Emp_begin >= '1930-01-01' AND Emp_end <= '1960-01-01' AND 
      Man_begin >= '1930-01-01' AND Man_end <= '1960-01-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you are trying to use a single query, i think you can just merge your date search together in `WHERE` clauses

```
SELECT EmployeeName FROM employees
WHERE start BETWEEN '1930-01-01' AND '1960-01-01' 
AND end BETWEEN '1930-01-01' AND '1960-01-01'
```

[DEMO here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6ace4/2)

Answer (score 0):

```
   SELECT * 
     FROM employees e
LEFT JOIN managers m
       ON m.man_begin <= e.emp_begin
      AND m.man_end >= e.emp_begin
    WHERE e.emp_begin BETWEEN '1930-01-01' AND '1960-01-01';
```

Although I absolutely hate the inclusive BETWEEN for date ranges.. I expect you really want:

```
   SELECT * 
     FROM employees e
LEFT JOIN managers m
       ON m.man_begin <= e.emp_begin
      AND m.man_end >= e.emp_begin
    WHERE e.emp_begin >= '1930-01-01' 
      AND e.emp_begin < '1960-01-01';
```